# Scrapy - Grouping nested and sequential elements using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I would like to group repeating elements on a page using Scrapy, however there doesn't seam to be a lot of information for this particular example. Perhaps one of you would be kind enough to help me with this one.

---

**HTML**

This is the current HTML markup on the page I wish to scrape using Scrapy:

```
###############
# First group #
###############
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Heading1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo1URL">Foo1</a></td>
              <td>Bar1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo2URL">Foo2</a></td>
              <td>Bar2</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo3URL">Foo3</a></td>
              <td>Bar3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo4URL">Foo4</a></td>
              <td>Bar4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        ... 
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub-Heading1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name2</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>3</td>
            </tr>  
            ...      
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
################
# Second group #
################
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Heading2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo5URL">Foo5</a></td>
              <td>Bar5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo6URL">Foo6</a></td>
              <td>Bar6</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo7URL">Foo7</a></td>
              <td>Bar7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="Foo8URL">Foo8</a></td>
              <td>Bar8</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Sub-Heading2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name4</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Name6</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>6</td>
              <td>6</td>
            </tr>  
            ...      
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
################
# Third group #
################

# ... and so on
```

**Please note**: '...' indicates it repeats itself at variable instances for each page.

---

**DATA STRUCTURE**

This is how the above data in the HTML markup is structured:

```
--- Heading1
      --|--
          -|- Foo1 (Foo1URL)
           |- Bar1
          -|- Foo2 (Foo2URL)
           |- Bar2
        |--
          -|- Foo3 (Foo3URL)
           |- Bar3
          -|- Foo4 (Foo4URL)
           |- Bar4 
        |--
          -| ...
      --|-- Sub Heading1
           |- Name1
               |- 1
               |- 1    
               |- 1    
           |- Name2
               |- 2
               |- 2    
               |- 2   
           |- Name3
               |- 3
               |- 3    
               |- 3 
           |--
             -| ...  
--- Heading2
      --|--
          -|- Foo5 (Foo5URL)
           |- Bar5
          -|- Foo6 (Foo6URL)
           |- Bar6
        |--
          -|- Foo7 (Foo7URL)
           |- Bar7
          -|- Foo8 (Foo8URL)
           |- Bar8 
        |--
          -| ...
      --|-- Sub Heading2
           |- Name4
               |- 4
               |- 4    
               |- 4    
           |- Name5
               |- 5
               |- 5    
               |- 5   
           |- Name6
               |- 6
               |- 6    
               |- 6
           |--
             -| ... 
--- HeadingX
      --|-- ...and so on
```

The structure repeats itself on the page and other pages, so there are can be X number of these groups on a page.

---

**EXAMPLE SCRAPE DATA**

This is what I would like to scrape on the page:

```
[ (Heading1, Foo1, Foo1URL, Bar1, Foo2, Foo2URL, Bar2),
  (Heading1, Foo3, Foo3URL, Bar3, Foo4, Foo4URL, Bar4),
  ... 
  (Heading2, Foo5, Foo5URL, Bar5, Foo6, Foo6URL, Bar6),
  (Heading2, Foo7, Foo7URL, Bar8, Foo8, Foo8URL, Bar8),
  ... ]
```

and, then for the subheading:

```
[ (Heading1, Sub-Heading1, Name1, 1, 1, 1),
  (Heading1, Sub-Heading1, Name2, 2, 2, 2),
  (Heading1, Sub-Heading1, Name3, 3, 3, 3),
  ...
  (Heading2, Sub-Heading2, Name4, 4, 4, 4),
  (Heading2, Sub-Heading2, Name5, 5, 5, 5),
  (Heading2, Sub-Heading2, Name6, 6, 6, 6),
  ... ]
```

---

Comment: Anybody able to to help with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in such cases, when its hard to distinguish between html entries, you can try to count on the element position, meaning something like:

```
item = SomeItem()
item2 = SomeOtherItem()
for idx,t in enumerate(sel.xpath('/html/body/table')):
    if not idx % 2:
        item.field1 = t.xpath('tbody/tr/td/text()').extract()[0]
    else:
        content = t.xpath('tbody/tr/td[1]')
        item.field2 = content.xpath('table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/@href).extract()[0]
        item.field3 = content.xpath('table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()).extract()[0]
        sub_heading = t.xpath('tbody/tr/td[2]')
        item2.field1 = heading.xpath(...)
        ...
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's a good direction. Am I able to check the table I'm at by using the `Heading1` as a reference? Like there may be some other tables on the page, so if I can say check that the table is after the heading, I think it's called siblings in xpath but I think that's only for nested, that would be great.

Comment: Also, there can be `x` number of rows on each table, so how would you recommend of handle that one? Thank you for your time!

Comment: for your first question try `//td[text()='Heading1']` to go from there you can `//td[text()='Heading1']/../../following-sibling::table` etc.

Comment: Thank you guy! I didn't know you could recurse back like that!

Comment: I seem to have a problem with this solution, as there are other tables on the page that are in the middle of the page (which don't follow this structure) and then the groups continue again. I guess I need to some how find a way to group the Heading and the very next table together. Any help with this one @Guy?